# HTTPS between Service Fabric services

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, azure-service-fabric, self-signed-certificate

I have two Service Fabric stateless services in the same cluster, one of them is exposed to the internet and it communicates with the second one (not exposed to the public internet). Currently, the requests are going through HTTP but I want to use HTTPS instead. I could successfully use a self-signed certificate, but since it isn't signed by a CA I had to ignore the authority validation. Since the requests are done within the same cluster and the second service isn't exposed to the public internet I can't get a certificate from a CA. Is using a self-signed cert ok in this scenario? Is there another solution to secure interservice communication?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom root CA as a self signed certificate, install that root CA on your cluster so it will be considered as a valid CA. Then use that root CA to generate the SSL certificates for both services.

The post below explains how to generate custom root CA and self signed certs
https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309